# In Gin-Rummy, what are the chances to start with a Gin?

Tags: statistics, gin-rummy

In Gin-Rummy, in the start of a round players draw 10 cards.

What is the probability to draw 10 cards such that all the cards are part of some  meld?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three Independent sources counted *about* 136,694 Gin hands, out of 15.8B possible 10-cards hands.

1. **[2+2 forum post](https://forumserver.twoplustwo.com/25/probability/probability-being-dealt-gin-528078/):** 1 in ~118,000.  Using brute force which checked for Gin each of the 15.8B hands.
2. **[Rulemonger's analysis](https://entropyclay.wordpress.com/2020/09/28/gin/):** 136,694 in 15,820,024,220 or **1 in ~115733**
3. **How to Win at Gin Rummy:** 1 in ~117,000, according to the book [How to Win at Gin Rummy: Playing for Fun and Profit](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=eS4IswEACAAJ&source=gbs_book_other_versions) which state that there are 136,694 Gin hands out of 15,820,024,220 hands.  See page 65:
   [image: gin hand - starting amount of deadwood]

Comment: I've made a combinatorics count as well, as further confirmation: https://entropyclay.wordpress.com/2020/09/28/gin/

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: this count is flawed, it doesn't recognize sets of three that include a spade. The correct number is given in the accepted answer. When the code is corrected, it gives the 136,694 unique gin hands, matching the accepted answer.

Original:

1 in 308,984, according to [Andrew Inwood's analysis](https://canadianandrew.wordpress.com/2016/09/13/odds-of-dealing-gin/), which includes [source code](https://bitbucket.org/ainwood87/gin/src/master/).

Comment: Does that include being able to pick up a visible discard to make Gin on your first turn?  I'm inclined to think it doesn't, because I've done that twice, and I only play gin for an hour, once a week, for the past 4-5 years.

Comment: it does not.  Just the first 10 cards.  Getting a gin in the first turn (out of the first 11 cards) is a better (much harder question

Comment: This appears to count Aces as low-only, I assume this is why it disagrees with the other counts. See GinManager::SetUsableCards in https://bitbucket.org/ainwood87/gin/src/master/GinManager.cpp, which has nine types of length-five runs, when it should be 10.

Comment: Because Aces are low-only, in the standard rules of Gin (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gin_rummy#Objective)

Comment: @DanTilkin, also the other counts use Ace as low-only.

Comment: Found it: it doesn't recognize three-of-a-kinds that include a spade, so undercounts the number of gin hands accordingly.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson Interesting. Either my memory of playing is wrong, or we were using non-standard rules. I didn't even notice the missing spade check.

Comment: @DanTilkin, In the "official" rules aces are only low, however there are many variations where aces can be either high or low, for example TCC-Gin https://www.pagat.com/docs/TCCGinBook.pdf